# How to set a value in a pandas dataframe column base on a specific interval condition without repetition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a dataframe such that:

1. **df.Condition == A , df.Output =  True**
2. **Next three rows after df.Output =  True  (even when Condition=="A", df.Output = None**

Original df

| Condition |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| B |
| A |
| B |
| A |
| B |

Desired output:

| Condition | Output |
| --- | --- |
| A | True |
| B | None |
| A | None |
| B | None |
| A | True |
| B | None |
| A | None |
| B | None |

Can this be achieved through a vectorised method without resorting to use loop? Thanks!

Comment: can you post your df as example plz?

Comment: Just for clarity, can you confirm that "Output" is not pre-existing and should be created solely from "Condition"

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the bad phrasing. The "Output" column does not exist in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't vectorize this operation since it's inherently iterative. You must use a loop (you can however improve its efficiency with [numba](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation)):

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(s, delay=3):
    out = []
    wait = 0                  # default waiting time: 0
    for v in s:
        if v and not wait:    # if True and no wait
            out.append(True)  # then it's a True
            wait = delay      # set to wait the next "delay" steps
        else:
            out.append(None)  # else it's a None
        if wait:
            wait -= 1         # decrement waiting time
    return out

df['Output'] = f(df['Condition'].eq('A').to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
  Condition Output
0         A   True
1         B   None
2         A   None
3         B   None
4         A   True
5         B   None
6         A   None
7         B   None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'A','Result'] = 'True'
df.loc[df['Condition'] == 'B','Result'] = 'None'
```

Comment: Have you checked the output? ;)

Comment: Ok I replaced False with None

Comment: Still not what is requested ;)

Comment: Why not, what am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't have `True` if there was already one in the last `N` rows.